# pdfMake Cannot read property '_calcWidth' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfmake

I am trying to generate a pdf out of an HTML table. The table has two columns, the headers are names of two objects. Each of these objects has a list and the rows of the table correspond to the values of these lists. I am using pdf make, below is my code, when I am doing  `this.rowContent.push("","");` inside a loop i am getting the following error `Cannot read property '_calcWidth' of undefined`, but the same line  `this.rowContent.push("","")` works outside of the loop.

```
 this.makePDF = function(){

   this.rowContent = [];
   this.tableheaders = [];
   this.tableContent = [];

    for(var i = 0;i<this.values1.length;i++){
         this.tableheaders[i] = {text: this.values[i].name,  bold: true, alignment: 'center'}
    }

    this.tableContent.push(this.tableheaders);

    for(var j = 0;j<this.length;j++){

        this.rowContent.push("","");
    }

    this.tableContent.push(this.rowContent);
    this.rowContent = [];

    var docDefinition = {

           header: 'simple text',
           content: [
             {
               table: {
                 headerRows: 1,
                 widths: [ '*', '*' ],

                 body:this.tableContent
               }
             }
           ]
         };

    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case what was causing this issue was the fact,
That I exported to pdf from a table where the number of headers() and a number of columns() weren't the same.
Once I fix it and ensure that the table has the same number of headers and row columns the problem was gone.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to put -1 in

```
for(var j = 0;j<this.length - 1;j++)
for(var i = 0;i<this.values1.length -1;i++)
```

when you say

```
i < this.length
```

for i = this.length you try to access to a element who doesn't exist in the Array.

```
A = ['I','M]
A.length = 2 
A[0] = 'I
A[1]= 'M'
```

but A[2] is undefined, because it doesn't exist in A

In more, I think you forgot to put the variable where you want to apply length function, for

```
    for(var j = 0;j<this.length - 1;j++)
```

Comment: Hi Graziella .. length is the just a variable to which i am assigning a number. and adding -1 to did not fix it .

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is that the `widths` array has too many elements. It should always cointain as many elements as the arrays in the `body` of the table.

> How to do it:

```
content: [{
  table: {
    headerRows: 1,
    widths: ['*', '*'],
    body: [
      ['item1', 'item2'],
      ['item1', 'item2']
    ]
  }
}]
```

> How not to do it:

```
content: [{
  table: {
    headerRows: 1,
    widths: ['*', '*','*'],
    body: [
      ['item1', 'item2'],
      ['item1', 'item2']
    ]
  }
}]
```

Comment: This was my issue I had an extra column that supposed not to be there, copy and paste disease...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem when I was generating a table without the colSpan/rowSpan value.
Here is an example how to do it the right way from: http://pdfmake.org/playground.html

```
    {
        style: 'tableExample',
        table: {
            body: [
                [
                    {
                        colSpan: 3,
                        text: 'colSpan: 3\n\nborder:\n[false, false, false, false]',
                        fillColor: '#eeeeee',
                        border: [false, false, false, false]
                    },
                    '',
                    ''
                ],
                [
                    'border:\nundefined',
                    'border:\nundefined',
                    'border:\nundefined'
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
```